# SQL Azure EF Database First Connection String in Azure Management Portal

Tags: entity-framework, azure, connection-string, azure-sql-database, azure-management

I have a site running n Azure, which uses EF Database First model.

If I embed the connection string in the web.config and deploy all is rosy.

```
<add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/App_Code.Model.csdl|res://*/App_Code.Model.ssdl|res://*/App_Code.Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=my.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=myTest_DB;User ID=***;Password=***; MultipleActiveResultSets=False'"  providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

But, I don't want the connection string in the web.config because it contains credentials.

So I moved it to the connection string area in Azure Properties.

First issue I hit is getting metadata invalid keyword error.

I solved that by changing the type from SQL Database to Custom.

[image]

However, I now get this error:

> The connection string 'MyEntities' in the application's configuration
>   file does not contain the required providerName attribute."

I've trawled the web and tried many variations of the connection string but not yet found the correct one.

*Note: I guess I could make this an app setting and move the initialisation of the string to code, but even if only for curiosity sake I would like to know how to do it via the portal.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is not the connection string, but the inability to specify the `providerName` from the portal.

Try publishing with a local or dummy connection string in place, and overwriting it as you have in the Azure Application Settings. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18964294/94853

Comment: Ha, so simple! Thanks a bunch.